# An error has occured opening the folder on the FTP server. Make sure you have permission to access the folder

Tags: windows, iis, ftp

> I cannot access the folder in my FTP server remotely.

[FTP unable to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5K7x.png)

> I can login using cmd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzXUG.png)

Comment: Try to download/upload something at command prompt, and probably you can reproduce the same error. Not surprising if you don't have firewall configured for active mode.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

This could be the FTP Firewall Support issue, you can try the following steps to solve the problem:

1.Go to IIS Manger -> Server name, double click on FTP Firewall Support.

2.Change the Data channel Port Range to 0-0 and remove the External IP addresses of Firewall in it is used for internal only.

[image]

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions. Vote them to be closed and moved to the appropriate site and answer them there.